# Copying elements from 2D array into another one

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I've been trying to copy the elements from a multidimensional array into another one. My goal is to get the elements from the first array 'bikeBrands' and try to put them in the new array 'bikeBrands2' but 'bikeBrands2' keeps coming as undefined.

```
  const bikeBrands = [];
  bikeBrands[0] = ['Susuki', 'Kawasaki'];
  bikeBrands[1] = ['Honda', 'KTM'];

  const bikeBrands2 = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < bikeBrands.lenght; i++)
    bikeBrands2[i] = bikeBrands[i].slice();


  console.log(bikeBrands2);
```

Comment: instead of doing bikeBrands2[i] just do bikeBrands2.push(bikeBrands[i].slice())

Answer (score 0):

You made a typo in the length keyword. That's the issue.

```
for (var i = 0; i < bikeBrands.length; i++)
bikeBrands2[i] = bikeBrands[i].slice();

console.log(bikeBrands2);
```

Output:

```
[ [ 'Susuki', 'Kawasaki' ], [ 'Honda', 'KTM' ] ]
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use concat function and emerge the first array with seconde without using a boocle

```
let bikeBrands = [];
bikeBrands[0] = ['Susuki', 'Kawasaki'];
bikeBrands[1] = ['Honda', 'KTM'];

let bikeBrands2 = [];
        
bikeBrands2 = bikeBrands2.concat(bikeBrands);

console.log(bikeBrands2);
```

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is using spread operator. Cheers!

```js
const bikeBrands = [];
  bikeBrands[0] = ['Susuki', 'Kawasaki'];
  bikeBrands[1] = ['Honda', 'KTM'];


const copybikeBrands = [...bikeBrands];

console.log("the copy", copybikeBrands)
```